# TikZ: connecting nodeparts

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees

I'm new to TikZ. Last couple of hours in fact.

I was wondering if there was a way of connecting `nodepart`s from different nodes.

Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow=right,    
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm,level distance=5.2cm},
  edge from parent/.style={draw=white},
]

\node[name=block1, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, draw=black]
  { \textbf{Block 1}
    \nodepart{second} connect to a
    \nodepart{third} connect to b
    \nodepart{fourth} connect to c
  }
  child {
    node[name=block2, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, draw=black]
     {  \textbf{Block 2}
        \nodepart{second} \Huge{a}
        \nodepart{third} \Huge{b}
        \nodepart{fourth} \Huge{c}
    }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: connect the dots]

I want to connect the nodeparts of block 1 to 2. I was hoping I could do something like:

```
\draw [->] (block1.second.east) -- (block2.second.west);
```

...but alas, it did not work, and I couldn't figure out how to do this.

(I guess I could just stack plain nodes and connect them as per usual, but still interested in a solution here.)

Comment: You are almost there. Just remove the second set of dots : `\draw [->] (block1.second east) -- (block2.second west);`

Comment: Hehe. Thanks! (My hopes for TikZ are restored!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The multipart nodes have anchors called `<node name>.one`, `<node name>.two east`, etc., that allow you to reference the individual parts. The anchors for the `rectangle split` node are shown in the section `Shapes with Multiple Text Parts` of the [pgfmanual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). As percusse points out in the comment on the question, the node parts can also be referenced using `.second`, `.third`, etc., although this is not documented in the manual.

As a side note, for positioning your nodes in this case, I would not use a tree but rather the `positioning` library, which introduces the syntax `right = of <node name>` to place new nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[name=block, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, draw] 
  { \textbf{Block 1}
    \nodepart{second} connect to a
    \nodepart{third} connect to b
    \nodepart{fourth} connect to c
  };

\node[name=block2, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, draw, right= of block] 
     {  \textbf{Block 2}
        \nodepart{second} \Huge{a}
        \nodepart{third} \Huge{b}
        \nodepart{fourth} \Huge{c}
    };
\draw [-latex] (block.two east) -- (block2.two west);
\draw [-latex] (block.three east) -- (block2.three west);
\draw [-latex] (block.four east) -- (block2.four west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```