# No borders on left/right side of tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I want to draw something like the following (photoshop'd) rendering: [image: photoshop'd]
This image consists of three `\node`s, each using a different border. The whole thing is pinned on a `chain`, because in my actual situation I am creating something like the [syntax diagram in the TikZ tutorial (p60)](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=60).

Right now, I have a MWE that renders borders between the L, C and R `\node`s as well, but I want those to disappear without a change to the 'outside' borders.

My actual code:
[image: actual]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,
    node distance=5mm,
    every node/.style={on chain},
    connect/.style={join=by ->},
    point/.style={coordinate},
    l/.style={draw, fill=cyan!50, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle right arc=0},
    c/.style={draw, fill=green!50},
    r/.style={draw, fill=orange!50, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle left arc=0},
    cozy/.style={node distance=-\pgflinewidth}]
\node[point] (p1) {};
\node [l, connect] (l) {L};
{[cozy]
\node [c] (c) {C};
\node [r] (r) {R};
}
\node[point, connect] (p2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Custom Borders (revised)

I have followed [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128363/31877), [@Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161561/31877), and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76461/31877).
I tried drawing the borders manually, using slightly different approaches for each section of my shape. All of them have their own drawbacks:

- *applied in L:* leaving the `\node`'s `line width` at the default (`\pgflinewidth`), `draw=none` will cause the `\node` to contain surrounding space of width `0.5*\pgflinewidth`. In order to draw a border within the `\node`'s dimensions, the border must not grow beyond this space. Unfortunately, part of the the border's inside is drawn behind the filler, leaving it looking too slim. Additionally, the eastern anchor points now look as if they're off by a bit.
- *applied in C:* setting the `\node`'s `line width=0` at least makes sure all the anchor points (esp. eastern & western) in the right place. However, this way, the entire border is drawn behind the filler.
- *applied in R:* setting the `\node`'s `line width=0`, and drawing the border *outside* of the filler. This causes the border to be outside the `\node`'s dimensions, making it overlap with connecting objects.

[image: custom borders]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,scopes,shapes.misc,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreforeground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground,foreforeground}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,
    node distance=5mm,
    every node/.style={on chain},
    connect/.style={join=by ->},
    point/.style={coordinate},
    l/.style={line width=\pgflinewidth, fill=cyan!50, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle right arc=0, append after command={% <= for the border
        \pgfextra{\begin{pgfinterruptpath}\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
            \draw[] let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p2=($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p3=($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p4=($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \n1={0.5*(\y2-\y3)} in
                (\p1) -- (\p2) arc(90:270:\n1) -- (\p4);
        \end{pgfonlayer}\end{pgfinterruptpath}}
    }},
    c/.style={line width=0, fill=green!50, append after command={% <= for the border
        \pgfextra{%                 
            \begin{pgfinterruptpath}\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
                \draw[] let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p2=($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p3=($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p4=($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$) in
                (\p1) -- (\p2) (\p3) -- (\p4);
            \end{pgfonlayer}\end{pgfinterruptpath}
        }
    }},
    r/.style={line width=0, fill=orange!50, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle left arc=0, append after command={% <= for the border
        \pgfextra{%                 
            \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
            \draw[] let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p2=($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p3=($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p4=($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \n1={0.5*(\y1-\y4)} in
                (\p3) -- (\p4) arc(-90:90:\n1) -- (\p2);
            \end{pgfinterruptpath}
        }
    }}
]
\node[point] (p1) {};
\node [l, connect] (l) {L};
{[node distance=-0.5\pgflinewidth]
\node [c] (c) {C};}
{[node distance=0]
\node [r] (r) {R};}
\node[point, connect] (p2) {};

\node[font=\tiny, cyan, below=of l] (lbl l-se) {l.se};
\draw[red,->] (lbl l-se) -- (l.south east);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreforeground}%apparently, using layer 'foreground' in 'append after command' brings the entire node to the front, which we don't want!
\node[font=\tiny, green, below=of c, yshift=2mm] (lbl c-ne) {c.ne};
\draw[red,->] (lbl c-ne) -- (c.north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\node[font=\tiny, orange, below=of r] (lbl r-sw) {r.sw};
\draw[red,->] (lbl r-sw) -- (r.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**How do I make sure my custom borders are within the `\node`'s borders, and drawn *on top* of `\node`'s filler color?**
I have attempted to use `\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}` to bring borders to the foreground, but all that seems to do in `append after command` is bring the entire `\node` to the foreground, with the border still behind the filler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce/increase them by `0.5\pgflinewidth`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,scopes,shapes.misc,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,
    node distance=5mm,
    every node/.style={on chain},
    connect/.style={join=by ->},
    point/.style={coordinate},
    l/.style={fill=cyan!50, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle right arc=0, append after command={% <= for the border
        \pgfextra{%
            \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
            \draw[] let \p1=(\tikzlastnode.north west), \p2=(\tikzlastnode.south east), \n1={0.5*(\y1-\y2)} in
                ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$) -- (\tikzlastnode.north west) arc(90:270:\n1) -- ($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$);
            \end{pgfinterruptpath}
        }
    }},
    c/.style={fill=green!50, append after command={% <= for the border
        \pgfextra{%
            \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
            \draw[] ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$) -- ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$) ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$) -- ($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$);
            \end{pgfinterruptpath}
        }
    }},
    r/.style={fill=orange!50, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle left arc=0, append after command={% <= for the border
        \pgfextra{%
            \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
            \draw[] let \p1=(\tikzlastnode.north west), \p2=(\tikzlastnode.south east), \n1={0.5*(\y1-\y2)} in
                ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$) -- (\tikzlastnode.north east) arc(90:-90:\n1) -- ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$);
            \end{pgfinterruptpath}
        }
    }},
    cozy/.style={node distance=-\pgflinewidth}]
\node[point] (p1) {};
\node [l, connect] (l) {L};
% introduced space here on purpose, to demonstrate too long borders
\node [c] (c) {C};
{%[cozy]
\node [r] (r) {R};
}
\node[point, connect] (p2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Response to Revised OP:

May be I don't understand your requirement properly, but is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,scopes,shapes.misc,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
%\pgfdeclarelayer{foreforeground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}%,foreforeground}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,
    node distance=5mm,
    every node/.style={on chain},
    connect/.style={join=by ->},
    point/.style={coordinate},
    l/.style={line width=\pgflinewidth, fill=cyan!50, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle right arc=0, append after command={% <= for the border
        \pgfextra{\begin{pgfinterruptpath}\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
            \draw[] let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p2=($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0,-\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p3=($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0,\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p4=($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$),
                \n1={0.5*(\y2-\y3)} in
                (\p1) -- (\p2) arc(90:270:\n1) -- (\p4);
        \end{pgfonlayer}\end{pgfinterruptpath}}
    }},
    c/.style={line width=0, fill=green!50, append after command={% <= for the border
        \pgfextra{%
            \begin{pgfinterruptpath}\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
            \draw[] let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p2=($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p3=($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0.5\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p4=($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)$) in
                (\p1) -- (\p2) (\p3) -- (\p4);
            \end{pgfonlayer}\end{pgfinterruptpath}
        }
    }},
    r/.style={line width=0, fill=orange!50, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle left arc=0, append after command={% <= for the border
        \pgfextra{%
            \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
            \draw[] let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p2=($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p3=($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \p4=($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
                \n1={0.5*(\y1-\y4)} in
                (\p3) -- (\p4) arc(-90:90:\n1) -- (\p2);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \end{pgfinterruptpath}
        }
    }}
]
\node[point] (p1) {};
\node [l, connect] (l) {L};
{[node distance=-0.5\pgflinewidth]
\node [c] (c) {C};}
{[node distance=0]
\node [r] (r) {R};}
\node[point, connect] (p2) {};

%\node[font=\tiny, cyan, below=of l] (lbl l-se) {l.se};
%\draw[red,->] (lbl l-se) -- (l.south east);
%
%\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreforeground}%apparently, using layer 'foreground' in 'append after command' brings the entire node to the front, which we don't want!
%\node[font=\tiny, green, below=of c, yshift=2mm] (lbl c-ne) {c.ne};
%\draw[red,->] (lbl c-ne) -- (c.north east);
%\end{pgfonlayer}

%\node[font=\tiny, orange, below=of r] (lbl r-sw) {r.sw};
%\draw[red,->] (lbl r-sw) -- (r.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing `c/.style` to

```
c/.style={line width=0, fill=green!50, append after command={% <= for the border
    \pgfextra{%
        \begin{pgfinterruptpath}\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \draw[] let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-0\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
            \p2=($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
            \p3=($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)$),
            \p4=($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(-0\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)$) in
            (\p1) -- (\p2) (\p3) -- (\p4);
        \end{pgfonlayer}\end{pgfinterruptpath}
    }
}},
```

gives

[image]

But you'll need TikZ 3 for this. TikZ 2 will draw the borders behind the filling colors.

Comment: I have used you answer to revise the "Custom Borders" section of my question. I'm having trouble with backgrounds/foregrounds now, as well as appropriate anchor point positions.

Comment: I want a continuous border around the LCR-combination. But on my system (MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4902 (1.40.14) (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)) your updated answer does not produce a visible border. The border ends up *behind* the fill color. In my revised question I was merely experimenting with 3 different ways of creating a "custom border".

Comment: I did a fresh install of MiKTeX 2.9.5105. Now `pdflatex --version` tells me `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4902 (1.40.14)`. `\listfiles` reveals that I have `tikz.sty 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)` and `pgf.sty 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)`. But the borders are still behind the fill color.

Comment: @derabbink It seems, it won't work with `tikz` v2.1, I don't have enough time to test. Can you install `tikz` v3 manually?

Answer (score 6):

One possibility would be to use a multipart rectangle from the `shapes.multipart` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style={
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split parts=3,
  rectangle split horizontal,
  draw,
  rounded corners=6pt,
  rectangle split part fill={cyan!50, green!50,orange!50},
  rectangle split draw splits=false
  }
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode] at (2,3) {L\nodepart{two}C\nodepart{three}R};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have investigated this option, but it appears that I cannot use coordinates such as `c.south west` in other `\node`s. For me, that is a requirement. Maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: Two years have passed but since the question was relevant to you, is currently relevant for me, and might become relevant to others, I still give a comment. You can refer to those nodeparts by `<parentnode>.two south west`. Please find some more info in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35991/77985.